# Can we add custom network on safe wallet web?

Tags: gnosis-safe

i wanto add custom RPC network on safe wallet. just want to know is there any method through that we do same or i am just waisting my time.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can add a custom RPC network to a wallet, including the Gnosis Safe wallet.

You'll need to know the network's RPC URL, chain ID, currency symbol, and explorer URL.

However, the exact process can vary between wallet applications.

So, you're not wasting your time, just make sure to check the specific steps for your particular wallet.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ari, thanks for your reply. now i am able to connect my custom network withs safe wallet. but now while sending token to any address getting one error : "usd?trusted=false"  can you help me in that ...as i m not getting any solution.